# When should I incentivize parents to post about my kids app on social media?

Tags: social-media

I have a reading app that's designed to be used by kids. However, I anticipate that the parents will have to set it up, at least initially. I want to prompt the parents to post about my app on social media. My question is, when should I prompt them?

Comment: Is the idea to have the parents all join the same discussion at the same time, to make sure that setup was successful?

Comment: Hi Montana, in what way is this about User Experience? This sounds more like a marketing question...

Comment: @Nash & StacyH: I want to include a prompt in my app for parents to share my app on their social media pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Look at the <s>Users'</s> Customers' Goals and Motivations

Initially your customer (parents) goal is to set up the application and provide to their child. Interrupting that goal is likely to cause frustration; frustration that could decrease social media posts or lead to negative social media posts.

At what point during the setup and use of the app (the customer journey) would a parent be most inclined to share the app on social media? Perhaps during one of these points:

- Their child tells them they like the app
- Their child has completed their first book
- Their child has read every day for several days

The customer motivation for these is a sense of pride. That pride is an easy motivator to say "hey parent, share your child's proud moment with the world using social media.".

### Look at the Business Goals and Motivations

This gets back to what you want. You want social media posts. Most likely, you want exposure and marketing from satisfied customers.

Is the timing of the social media sharing important? If so, you may need to find a balance between the setup process and social media post timing to ask at a least intrusive time. If not, wait to request sharing when your customer is most inclined to want to share.

The sweet spot is when your customers' goals and your business goals align.

*Note that your users are the children. They have different goals and motivations than the parents (customers) and so they are identified differently.

Comment: Should the prompt to share on social media come during the setup phase of the app, or - perhaps - in a notification?

Comment: I would recommend doing it during one of the 3 achievements from the child instead of during setup. This will provide your parent proper motivation to post and share. There are various answers to HOW to do this: one option is that the parent receives a notification or email when the child finishes their first book that congratulates the parent and asks if they would like to share the accomplishment (and share the app).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to put this as a final step of whatever onboarding process you have prepared there for the parent. That way you don't interrupt it with something trivial, but you can use the occasion for the parent to share that they have set up the app.